# When is the relative dualizing sheaf trivializable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\varphi: X \to Y$ be a finite locally free morphism of schemes. Then we have a right adjoint $\varphi^!$ to the pushforward $\varphi_*$ of quasicoherent sheaves along $\varphi$. The relative dualizing sheaf $\omega_{X/Y}$ of $\varphi$ is defined to be $\varphi^! \mathcal{O}_Y$. My question is:

Are there any conditions on $X$, $Y$, or $\varphi$, which guarantee that $\omega_{X/Y}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X$?

If $\varphi$ is of degree $d$, we may construct the norm map $Nm_{\varphi}: \pi_* \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y$, and so under these circumstances we have a global section of $\omega_{X/Y}$ corresponding to the norm by adjunction. Can this map ever be an isomorphism?

Comment: $\omega _{X/Y}$ is trivial if $\varphi $ is étale. The converse holds if  $X$ and $Y$ are smooth over a field of characteristic $0$: if $\omega _{X/Y}=\omega _X\otimes \varphi ^*\omega _Y^{-1}$ is trivial, the homomorphism $\varphi ^*\Omega ^1_Y\rightarrow \Omega ^1_X$ is an isomorphism, hence $\varphi $ is étale.

Comment: @abx Thanks this is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. Could you help me understand why $\omega_{X/Y}$ is trivial if $\varphi$ is etale? Alternatively, a reference would suffice

Comment: One characterization of étale morphisms (EGA IV, Prop. 18.2.3) is that the bilinear form $\varphi _*\mathscr{O}_X\times  \varphi _*\mathscr{O}_X\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_Y$ given by trace of multiplication is a perfect duality. This implies that $\mathscr{H}om_{\mathscr{O}_X}(\varphi _*\mathscr{O}_X,\mathscr{O}_Y)$ is isomorphic, as a $\varphi _*\mathscr{O}_X$-module, to $\varphi _*\mathscr{O}_X$ — which just means that $\omega _{X/Y}$ is isomorphic to $\mathscr{O}_X$.

Comment: Is the notion of a [Gorenstein ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorenstein_ring) somehow relevant to this question?

Comment: @TimCampion It seems that [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C14) gives a description of $\omega_{X/Y}$ for a Gorenstein morphism of a similar flavor to abx's comment.